# Bounds on expected difference in coin toss sequence

Tags: probability, asymptotics, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

For any sequence of T fair coin flips, let $N_h, N_t$ be the number of heads and tails in the sequence.
I'm supposed to find asymptotically tight upper and lower bounds on $\mathbb{E}[|N_h - N_t|]$.

Now due the 'any sequence' I'm inclined to say $0 \leq \mathbb{E}[.] \leq T$. Both bounds will have a small probability of $\frac{1}{2^T}$ of happening (if T is even). 
However, I am not certain this is the right approach.

Using $N_t = T - N_h$ results in $\mathbb{E}[|2N_h - T|]$. 
Could use Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb{E}[|2N_h - T|] \geq |2\mathbb{E}[N_h] - T| = 0$.

Comment: Your bounds are valid "worst case" bounds, but the problem asks for an answer in terms of *expectations*, which means you can get a tighter bound than that.

Comment: I 'expected' that this was the case. However, I do not see how I can find those tighter bounds in terms of expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually compute this expectation exactly.

Consider the simpler case that we toss $2n$ coins. Then we have
$$
E[|N_h - N_t|]=E[|2 N_h - 2n|] = E[2 N_h - 2n; N_h>n]+E[2 N_t - 2n; N_t>n]
=2 E[2 N_h - 2n ; N_h>n] = 2 \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m > n} \binom{2n}{m}(2m-2n)=2^{1-2 n} (n+1) \binom{2 n}{n+1} \sim \frac{2 \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi }}.
$$

---

More details:

To see that
$$
\sum _{m=n+1}^{2 n} 2 (m-n) \binom{2 n}{m}
=\sum _{k=1}^n 2 k \binom{2 n}{k+n}
=
(n+1) \binom{2 n}{n+1}
$$
one can check that
$$
2 k \binom{2 n}{k+n}=\Delta _k(-(k+n) \binom{2 n}{k+n})
$$
where
$$
\Delta_k(f(n,k))=f(n,k+1)-f(n,k).
$$
The asymptotic approximation comes from [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

---

There is also a combinatorial proof of
$$
\sum _{k=1}^n 2 k \binom{2 n}{k+n}
=
(n+1) \binom{2 n}{n+1}
$$
Consider a bit string of length $2n$ with $n+k$ $1$'s and $n-k$ $0$'s. If we write the first $n$ bits and the second $n$ bits as a $2$ by $n$ matrix, there are $k$ columns with two $1$. Chose a $1$ in these $k$ columns and mark it. Keep the row with the mark unchanged, but turn the other row to be the XOR of both rows, except at this marked column. These gives a bit string of length $2n$ with $n+1$ $1$'s. An example of $n=5$ and $k=2$ would be
$$
11011\\
1010\bf{1}
$$
turns into
$$
01011\\
1010\bf{1}
$$
So the LHS of the equation we have to prove counts the number of such strings, as the RHS.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer! 
Would you mind elaborating on second to last step, where you rewrite the summation and remove m?

Comment: @NielsUitterdijk See the update.

Comment: Wow, thank you so so much for you this awesome explanation! 
This genuinely made my day!

Comment: I still lose you at the telescoping series.
$$\Delta_k(-(k+n)\binom{2n}{k+n}) = -(k+1+n)\binom{2n}{k+1+n} + (k+n)\binom{2n}{k+n} $$
$$= -(k+1+n)\frac{2n!}{(k+1+n)!2n!} + (k+n) \binom{2n}{k+n} $$
$$= -\binom{2n}{k+n}+ (k+n) \binom{2n}{k+n}$$
$$\neq 2k\binom{2n}{k+n} $$

Comment: You made a mistake in the 3rd equality.

Comment: Well, (k+1+n)! = (k+1+n) * (k+n)!. 
Then the (k+1+n) cancels and you remain with 2n! / ( (k+n)! 2n! )?

Comment: There is really no need to verify this at computer age. But if you really want to check every line, be careful. Humans are very very prone to computation mistakes. The first mistake you made is
$$
\binom{2n}{k+1+n}
=\frac{2n!}{(k+1+n)!(2n)!}
$$

Comment: Yeah you're right. Normally never even calculate these probabilities, just noticed I misused the notation. It's correct now. Thanks again.